# Polymorphic list and pointers

Tags: polymorphism

I am new to C++ and am struggling on polymorphism.
I have a project where I need to have a base class (let's say Master) and three derived class.

```
class Master {
public : 
   virtual void run(); 
   //Other attributes non-important for the topic
}

class Derived1 : public Master {
public:
   void run(); 
   //attributes
}

class Derived2 : public Master{
public :
   Derived2(Derived1* ptr1) {ptr = ptr1;} //there comes the cause of the problem
   void run(); 
private : 
   Derived1* ptr;
}
```

In my main I want to create a polymorphic list `vector<Master*> poly_list;`
But the problem is that this list only contains pointers on the Master class so even if it could call the right function run(); I cannot send the address of Derived1 to the constructor of Derived2.

I wanted to proceed like this :

```
int main
{
   vector<Master*> poly_list;
   poly_list.push_back(new Derived1());
   poly_list.push_back(new Derived2(poly_list[0])); 

   return 0
}
```

And when I compile the code the compiler tells me that it cannot convert type Master to Derived1 for the constructor.

Anybody has a way for this to work ? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take a pointer of `Derived1` before pushing it into the list:

```
vector<Master*> poly_list;

Derived1 *d=new Derived1();
poly_list.push_back(d);
poly_list.push_back(new Derived2(d));
```

Also, please, instead of using raw pointers, please, use `std::unique_ptr` smart pointer, so you will not leak memory if forgetting of doing `delete`, just as you are doing in your example.